# jsrender: how to include write space in jsrender expression

Tags: jsrender

if i have data as such: 
{My name: "Pete"}

and {{:My name}} gives me undefined value. Is there way to escape white space in expression? Please note i cannot change key ("My Name") to something contains no white space in given data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* need to have javascript objects (or JSON) with property names that include white-space (but this is best avoided if at all possible), then you can do so by writing:

Data:

```
{"My name": "Pete"}
```

Template

```
{{:#data["My name"]}}
```

`#data` is the current data. See http://www.jsviews.com/#paths and http://www.jsviews.com/#views